# import pandas error : Traceback (most recent call last) and expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: pandas, importerror

I installed GIS-Pro and use Jupyter. I believe Jupyter is in the GIS-Pro package. I use Jupyter to write Python codes. Since yesterday, I've got the following errors once executing import pandas as pd :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\2/ipykernel_23172/4080736814.py in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\ArcGISPro28\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
# numpy compat
from pandas.compat import (
np_version_under1p18 as _np_version_under1p18,
is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev,

C:\ArcGISPro28\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in <module>
np_version_under1p20)
from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
pa_version_under1p0,
pa_version_under2p0,

C:\ArcGISPro28\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pyarrow.py in <module>
pa_version = pa.__version__
palv = Version(_pa_version)
pa_version_under1p0 = _palv < Version("1.0.0")
pa_version_under2p0 = _palv < Version("2.0.0")

C:\ArcGISPro28\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\version\__init__.py in __init__(self, version)
# Validate the version and parse it into pieces
match = self._regex.search(version)
if not match:
raise InvalidVersion(f"Invalid version: '{version}'")

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: 1. Please show the full error. 2. Please show the code that you're using.

Comment: Just edited the question and added more details.